# Looking for Function or tips to extract Image Access Date and time in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an array of images in an folder,and i would like to read them in the order they copied in the folder i.e. for example there are three images if 1st image copied at 7.15 PM second at 7.45PM and third 7.55PM, i would like to read image which copied first in my folder in terms of time and date.? so how to sort image in that order? have any idea.
On the other hand,if right click on any image,and go to proporties,you will find three types of date i.e. Created date and time, modified date and time and access date and time. i would like to extract the access date and time of any image in matlab? how to do that? pls guide.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if there is a way to find the `atime` with a MATLAB function, you might have to do a `system` call. On most unix-like systems it would look something like this.

```
>> [status result] = system('ls -trlu')
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's possible to get the "access" date, but you can get the "modified" date with the dir function. By doing:

```
d = dir('directory');
time = d.date;
```

You then need to extract the relevant information from the string output of d.date and sort it accordingly.